# How can an Inno-Setup Preprocessor array be iterated over?

Tags: inno-setup

I've got an Inno Setuo Preprocessor array defined like this

```
#dim MYARRAY[3]
#define MYARRAY[0] 'foo'
#define MYARRAY[1] 'bar'
#define MYARRAY[1] 'baz'
```

No I would like to iterate over that array and put its contents into my translation, something like (non-working):

```
#define i 0
#define NUMBERELEMENTS 3

#for {i = 0; i < NUMBERELEMENTS; i++} {#MYARRAY[i]}
```

I found the following to be working, though, but is this the only doable way? Using `i` as a 'global' variable feels and simpy using a `#sub` feels just wrong.

```
#sub mysub
    {#MYARRAY[i]}
#endsub
#for {i = 0; i < NUMBERELEMENTS; i++} mysub
```

**Edit:**

What puzzled me, is that the following does not generate anything in the translation:

```
#define GetElement() MYARRAY[i]
#for {i = 0; i < NUMBERELEMENTS; i++} GetElement(i)
```

I'd expected it to generate one line of content per element of `MYARRAY` in the translation.

Comment: Global variable (if we're talking about the `MYARRAY` variable in your code) is perfectly fine for this task. What is your real intention for doing all of this ?

Comment: I've asked for the intention, since if you have in that array statements from a certain section, you may simply have a file with part of that section and just include this file into your current translation.

Comment: The intention behind is that I `#include` a bunch of other files and I would like to register a function in each included file, that get's called by the one and only `CurStepChanged`.

Currently, I do this like this: `#define PREINSTALLATIONHOOKS  PREINSTALLATIONHOOKS  + 'File1PreInstallationHook(); '` and later in the master file `if CurStep = ssInstall then begin {#PREINSTALLATIONHOOKS} end;`

This works, but I'd rather use an string-array item per hook instead of this single-string-concatenation.

Comment: I referred to `i` being the global variable for the `mysub`-call. Changed that in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `#sub` is the only thing that will work in this case.  Lines can currently only be output to the translation via either a previously defined `#sub` or via `#emit`, and the latter is a statement and cannot be called from expression context.

Note that you can mitigate the "icky global variable" feel a little by using `#define private i` before defining your sub and `#undef i` after the for loop.

An [issue has been filed](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/25) to enhance ISPP; you could try adding your voice there if you like.

Also, I already have a script that does exactly this sort of thing (hook into `CurStepChanged` via `#include`d files); it's not quite ready for public use yet but I was planning to clean it up and post it online in the next day or two.  So if you can hold on for a little bit longer then you could look at or use that.  (I'll edit my answer with a link once it's posted.)